# In Perl, how can I read pairs of space separated numbers from STDIN?

Tags: perl

I want 2 inputs in each line in a Perl program.

#### Input

```
4 3
3 1
5 7
```

We can do that in Ruby by this statement

```
a,b=gets.split.map &:to_i
```

Comment: is your data coming from a file?

Comment: @stevieb No,they are STDIN inputs

Comment: `my ($first, $second) = split " ", $input;`  Perl doesn't really have an integer type to declare or convert -- it will treat it as an integer when it's used in a numeric context (for example if you try to add to it).  If you want to validate it's an integer, that's another matter.  Many ways to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is coming from `STDIN` then read it line by line and `split` each line by space

```
while (<STDIN>) 
{
    my ($first, $second) = split;
    
    # Do what you need with $first and $second
}
```

This uses defaults of [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), with variable `$_` (to which input is assigned) and separator pattern `' '`, which stands for any amount of any space and discards leading and trailing spaces.  So `split;` above is the same as `split ' ', $_;`. The newline at the end of each input line is thus dropped.

For more flexibility one can omit the `STDIN` filehandle and use

```
while (<>) { ... }
```

in which case the files submitted on the command-line are all read line by line, or if no files were given then `STDIN` is read.

For reading of input and the *diamond operator* `<>` see [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators), and for the *default input and pattern-searching space* variable `$_` see [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

Checking user input is a whole other matter. To check that these are indeed numbers, a good tool is `looks_like_number` from the core module [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html).

I don't know what else there may be in your program, but I suggest to always start by

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
```

Comment: I honestly never realized that `' '` represented any whitespace with `split`, assuming incorrectly it meant a single-whitespace, but after a test, it does work. I always used `split /\s+/ ...` :)

Comment: @stevieb  I was hazy on it for the longest time, too!  It's like a well-kept secret, in plain sight and right in front of us (the default no less!) :). Sorry about a delayed response, sometimes I somehow miss to see comments.